# Switching focus away from windows with admin rights

Tags: windows-10, administrator, window, window-focus

When I have some app open with admin rights (ie. command prompt with admin rights), I cannot use either the task bar or ALT+TAB to switch to other  apps, unless that app is also running with admin rights.

I also cannot click out of the window to swap focus out of it.

[image]

In this image, for example (above), if I click out of the command prompt window, it does not switch focus to Google Chrome, this is very annoying and is hampering my productivity. Has someone else run into this bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Does it arrive when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: Ever learn anything here? I have exact same issue.